# How to expand the syntax in docsify

Tags: markdown, javascript-marked, docsify

I want to introduce some syntax inside markdown-preview-enhanced (a plugin of vscode), where should I edit it.
some like these
[Superscript Subscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGPp6.png)
[Mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGpx0.png)